# Javascript array and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

I'm just started with JavaScript and I have a little problem.

How do I use the `innerHTML` propriety to change the text in this element:

```js
(function showArray(){
  var names = new Array("Bob ","Alice ","Ceaser ","David");
  names.sort();

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML = names[i];
    // I'm only getting "David" as output!!
  }
})();
```

```html
<p id="loop">David Alice Bob Ceaser</p>
```

Comment: Change `innerHTML =` to `innerHTML +=`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this, you just need to join the names too.

```js
function showArray() {
  var names = new Array("Bob ", "Alice ", "Ceaser ", "David");
  names.sort();

  document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML = names.join(" ");
}

showArray();
```

```html
<p id="loop">David Alice Bob Ceaser</p>
```

Comment: This answer works, but if your intention is to just put text into a DOM node, you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. It's a good habit that may save you from code-injection attacks in the future, even though it doesn't matter in this example.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota `innerText` isn't standard. It should be `textContent`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Either way, the point is that you should be mindful of what you allow users to inject into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: your code can be reduced to

```js
 (function() {
   document.querySelector("#loop").innerHTML = 
       ["Bob ", "Alice ", "Ceaser ", "David"].sort().join(" ");
 }())
```

```html
<p id="loop"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, better use `Array.prototype.join` as suggested in [@DaveChen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316564/1529630).

However, you can't always use that. For those cases:

- DOM operations are slow. Therefore,

  - Don't use `getElementById` inside a loop. Instead, store the element in a variable before the loop.
  - Don't modify `innerHTML` at each iteration. Instead, update a string variable and only modify `innerHTML` after the loop.
- Creating arrays using `[]` is faster than with `Array` constructor, and it's shorter.

However, note that using `innerHTML` may produce html injection. If you just want to add text, better use `textContent` instead.

```js
(function showArray(){
  var names = ["Bob ","Alice ","Ceaser ","David"],
      el = document.getElementById("loop"),
      html = '';
  names.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) html += names[i];
  el.textContent = html;
})();
```

```html
<p id="loop">David Alice Bob Ceaser</p>
```